# Error - stored procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied in c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

When I'm trying to call store procedure and return the value from the procedure, I'm getting the error message - `procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied`

**Below is the c# code:**

```
using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("getservername8", conn1))
{
    command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command2.Parameters.Add("@s", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500);
    command2.Parameters["@s"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string server = (string)command2.Parameters["@s"].Value;
}
```

Below is the stored procedure:

```
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getservername9]
@s varchar(50)
as begin
declare @server_name varchar(500)
select  @server_name = short_description from [Event_alerts].[dbo].[event_alerts]
select @s= SUBSTRING(@server_name, CHARINDEX('-', @server_name) + 15, 50)
return @s
end
```

Stored procedure gets executed with no error.Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use ExecuteScalar instead of Executenonquery. Please refer..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 1):

Please make below changes to your code -

1. Mark your variable in the stored procedure as `output` like below -

   ```
    @s varchar(50) output
   ```
2. You cannot return varchar output values like you added in stored procedure. 
   Stored procedures always return integer values when you use return 
   statement [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). In your case you will get below error when executed - 
   (the same can be observed in .NET end as well).

   ```
   declare @s varchar(50)         
   exec [dbo].[getservername9] @s
   ```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data
>   type int.

3. `Remove the return statement` from stored procedure which will automatically return the value back to .NET code.
4. Finally make the stored ***procedure names consistent*** in both .NET and SQL procedure.

Answer (score 0):

First is to change your store procedure name, in the code you are using **getservername8** while your stored procedure name is **getservername9**, the second point you need to mark your parameter as output as show in the code below

**Code :**

```
using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("getservername", conn1))
{
   command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command2.Parameters.Add("@s", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500);
   command2.Parameters["@s"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   string server = (string)command2.Parameters["@s"].Value;
}
```

**Stored Procedure :**

```
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getservername]
@s varchar(50) output
as begin
declare @server_name varchar(500)
select  @server_name = short_description from [Event_alerts].[dbo].[event_alerts]
select @s= SUBSTRING(@server_name, CHARINDEX('-', @server_name) + 15, 50)
return @s
end
```

Comment: thanks it worked, I just removed return @s in stored procedure